# What should be the resource group of a user assigned managed identity?

Tags: azure, azure-managed-identity

I have app services running in different regions and I wish to assign all of them a managed identity. I cannot use a system managed identity, so it must be a user assigned one.

Creating one requires a resource group. So, the question is - what is the meaning of this resource group? After all, a managed identity is supposed to be a service principal under the hood, which do not belong to any resource groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resource group means a scope, it contains all the resources that you can control with the permission you assigned to the user-assigned identity. The permission you assigned to the user-assigned identity of the group will be inherited to all the resources in this resource group.

And yes, you're right, the managed identity is supposed to be a service principal under the hood, which do not belong to any resource groups, it just has some permissions of the resource group. If necessary, it can also have the permission of other groups. The difference between the user-assigned identity and service principal is that the user-assigned identity is a resource, but the service principal is not. So the user-assigned identity will display in a resource group, but the service principal not.

Comment: I am confused. If I have a resource in CentralUS - can it be assigned a User Assigned Managed Identity living under a resource group in EastUS2?